# An extension in use receive more than one call with leastrecent strategy

Tags: asterisk

I have a queue with some members.

The strategy is leastrecent.

Example:

Members: 101, 102, 103, 104

A call goes to 102, and 102 answer the call, and then, the ext. is in use.

Another call go in... the call goes to 102 too, when other extensions are Not In Use.

The config is:

```
[queuename]
announce-frequency=30
timeout=20
strategy=leastrecent
retry=5
queue-youarenext=queue-youarenext
queue-thereare=queue-thereare
queue-thankyou=queue-thankyou
queue-callswaiting=queue-callswaiting
music=default
maxlen=10
leavewhenempty=no
joinempty=Yes
eventwhencalled=yes
eventmemberstatus=no
context=
announce-holdtime=yes
wrapuptime=0
member => SIP/101,1
member => SIP/102,1
member => SIP/103,1
member => SIP/104,1
```

And call-limit is 2 because they want attended-transfers.

Is it right?

Another option to limit only 1 call from the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable "call waiting" option on the phone (most of the hardware and software phones have it). That way, the phone will be busy when trying to ring it, and it will go to the next agent.